# Display current service gateway url by using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm having trouble with finding a solution to display my current service url (registered with eureka and called up through a zuul gateway), like: `http://localhost:8080/services/someservice` with Thymeleaf in a client html page.

I've tried using `#httpServletRequest?.requestURL`, but that returns how the service is registered with Eureka, like: `user.somepackage.com:someservice:8011`, which isn't exactly what I want.

One possible solution I have for this is to assign a variable in Thymeleaf once with the url hardcoded, or do it through a Spring controller, but I don't think this is a neat.

Maybe somebody had a similar problem and found a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the *Reverse* proxy enabled, this should be straightforward using the configured routes mapping.

Consider the following route mapping example for the *ZUUL* API Gateway:

```yaml
zuul:
  routes:
    someservice:
      path: /services/someservice/**
      url: http://localhost:8080/services/someservice
```

You should be able to access the *context-relative* URL of your service within the client *Thymeleaf* template:

```html
<a th:href="@{/services/someservice/}">
<!-- OR -->
<form th:action="@{/services/someservice}">
<!-- ... -->
```

According to your need, you should use the appropriate [*Thymeleaf URL syntax*](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html). Here down the URL sample:

```html
<!-- Server-relative -->
<a th:href="@{~/services/someservice/}">

<!-- Context-relative -->
<a th:href="@{/services/someservice/}">
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I'm afraid it doesn't quite solve the problem, that I have: my url's within the application and attached .js or .css files get lost, when I browse around my application, f.e. go to `services/someservice/findsomething/id.` I have to statically insert the whole url into the `href` for them to work. Using `th:href` also doesn't work  without the whole url. That's why I was thinking of using some parameter to find the current url and that is returned as I mentioned above.

Comment: I just mentionned the context-relative URL scheme. I guess you would need a server-sensitive URL path. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the solution was quite simple:

```
<a th:href="@{~/services/someservice/logout}">
```

The most interesting part is the **~** sign. This defines the actual server url, like: http://localhost:8080. Just what I needed.